# Can you make useEffect run only once when one of the dependencies changes but not if it changes again?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am rendering conditional content and I have

```
const [content,setContent] = useState(0);
const [data,setData] = useState([]);
let render;
switch(content)
{ 
  case 0:render=<Something/>; break;
  case 1:render=<Else/> ;break;  
}
```

I have some data which will be used only if we render `<Else/>` but the user can switch between `<Something>` and `<Else/>` with a radio button anytime. I don't want to load the data if users never switches to `<Else/>`, but I also don't want to load data again in case he switches from `<Else/>` to `<Something/>` and then again to `<Else/>`

so using `useEffect(()=>{loadData().then(response=>setData(response.data))},[content])` not good idea since it will run everytime the user switches, but if I use `useEffect(()=>{loadData().then(response=>setData(response.data))},[])` and user never switched to  I loaded unnecessary data? How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Have a parent component that controls your state and can store / load both sets of data, when a view (Something or Else) is mounted have it call a function from the parent to load and store the data. It then doesn't matter if the children unmount as it will be the parent controlling component that will be storing the data about each one, allowing you to avoid reacquiring the data when swapping back / forth and to only load the initial view data at the start.

Comment: You can initialize data to null and do a null check `!data && loadData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do it's validate inside the `useEffect` hook if the data you need was already loaded. If that's the case, then just avoid making the request.

Or

Pass the responsability of fetch the data to the child components (`Else` and `Something`). That way it will only be executed when that component it's rendered.